# Add items to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code to add data to an array, however when ever i display the array it only shows one item in the array. Am i doing something wrong?

Basically i have a textfield and a button when the user types there name in the field it then should be added to the array however as i stated above im only seeing one name when i run nslog.

```
NSMutableArray *players = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

[players addObject: self.playersnametext.text];
    NSLog(@"%@", players);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Assuming you have CR or comma separated names in your textfield like:
`"name1, name2, name3"`

A simple way to "split" this string into an array is to use:

```
 NSArray *players = [self.playersnametext.text componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

Hope that helps. See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

if you add your "players" like this :

```
NSMutableArray *players = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

[players addObject:@"player1"];
[players addObject:@"player2"];
[players addObject:@"player3"];
NSLog(@"%@", players);
```

you can get them like that :

```
[players objectAtIndex:0]; //player1
[players objectAtIndex:1]; //player2
[players objectAtIndex:2]; //player3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Store names (multiple for each player)
    NSMutableArray *playerNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   @[@"P1Name1",@"P1Name2",@"P1Name3",@"P1Name4"],
                                   @[@"P2Name1",@"P2Name2",@"P2Name3",@"P2Name4"],
                                   @[@"P3Name1",@"P3Name2",@"P3Name3",@"P3Name4"],nil];

    //Fetch Names
    [[playerNames objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
    [[playerNames objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0];
    [[playerNames objectAtIndex:2] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Is this something that you were looking for? Store multiple names for each player and extract it based on an index (which you can increment based on a logic).